# Git annex 400 Error when initializing remote S3 repository

Tags: amazon-s3, git-annex

I'm trying to initialize a *git annex* remote repository using:

```
git annex initremote cloud type=S3 encryption=none bucket=some-bucket
```

But I am getting the following error:

> initremote cloud (checking bucket...) (creating bucket in US...) git-annex: S3Error
>   {s3StatusCode = Status {statusCode = 400, statusMessage = "Bad Request"}, s3ErrorCode = 
>   "InvalidRequest", s3ErrorMessage = "The authorization mechanism you have provided is not 
>   supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.", s3ErrorResource = Nothing, s3ErrorHostId = Just
>   "", s3ErrorAccessKeyId = Nothing, s3ErrorStringToSign = Nothing, 
>   s3ErrorBucket = Nothing, s3ErrorEndpointRaw = Nothing, s3ErrorEndpoint = Nothing}

I was following [this manual](https://git-annex.branchable.com/tips/using_Amazon_S3/).

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

That's usually caused by an old `openssl` version.

I managed to solve it on an old server (Ubuntu 16) using `conda` to manage all `git-annex` dependencies inside an env and adding the `signature=v4` arg to the `initremote` command

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge git-annex=*=alldep*
```

More info on installing `git-annex` with conda in its forum: https://git-annex.branchable.com/install/conda/